# Fixed column in ReactTable component

Tags: css, reactjs, react-table

Could we fix a column when we get a horizontal column with smaller pages?

For example could we fix the column `firstName` in [this](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/simple-table) example.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 6):

react-table does not support fixed columns, issue is opened [Sticky columns](https://github.com/react-tools/react-table/issues/848). But there is already implemented workaround, you can find sources [github](https://github.com/guillaumejasmin/react-table-hoc-fixed-columns) or [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table-hoc-fixed-columns) (link taken from thread [Sticky columns](https://github.com/react-tools/react-table/issues/848)). 
[Online Demo](https://guillaumejasmin.github.io/react-table-hoc-fixed-columns/). 
Thanks to GuillaumeJasmin.

Answer (score 6):

without using react-table or any npm dependencies fixed column can be achieved only via css tricks with in react app.

[image: Fixed column react-table]

Find the full code [Here](http://www.recompile.in/2019/11/react-fixed-table-header-code-without.html)

Step 1 : divide the dataset of fixed and scrollable columns

Step 2 : place two tables side by side in such a way that it looks as single table

Step 3 : Wrap both with a single div and use a fixed width, give fixed width or responsive width for second one and make overflow-x: scroll; so that it keeps scrolling horizontally,while first tables columns will not be scrollable

Answer (score 5):

Since v7 of `react-table` was released recently and it's a complete rewrite, [react-table-hoc-fixed-columns](https://github.com/guillaumejasmin/react-table-hoc-fixed-columns) is not compatible with it. If you are using version <7 then see @Alex's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50085101/4248342) above.

For `react-table` v7, you can use [react-table-sticky](https://github.com/GuillaumeJasmin/react-table-sticky) by the same author.

Comment: The above library isn't working with react-window into the picture. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61968493/react-table-v7-fixed-column-with-react-window) the issue. Can anyone help?

Comment: @priyanshusinha Have you tried https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-virtual? It's from the author of react-table itself and very easy to setup. Here is an example: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-virtual#sample

Answer (score 1):

Try below things, it might help:

In React, CSS part in component itself:

```
fix: { 
 position: 'sticky',
 right: 0,
 padding: '11px 16px',
 boxShadow: '0px 4px 4px 0px #999',
},
fixColumn: {        
 position: 'sticky',       
 right: 0,
},
```

In my case of - Material-UI DataTable

```
<MuiTable component="table" {...getProps()}>
          <TableHead>
            {headerGroups.map(prop => (
              <TableRow {...prop.getAllHeaderProps()}>
                {prop.headers.map((column, index) => {
                  const fixColIndex = column.id === 'column_id_need_to_fix' ? index : '';);
                  const fixHeaderProps = column.getHeaderProps({
                    className: clsx({ [classes.fixColumn]: fixColIndex }, column.className),
                  });return (
                <TableCell {...fixHeaderProps}></TableCell>
              );
            })}
          </TableRow>
        ))}
      </TableHead>
```

Under TableBody

```
const Props = props.getProps({
                    className: clsx(
                      {
                        [classes.fix]: props.column.id === fixColumnId,
                      },
                    ),
                  });
                  return (
                    <TableCell {...Props}>
                      {prop.render('Cell')}
                    </TableCell>
                  );
```