# Fixed Column in React-Table

Tags: reactjs

I'm using an excellent data table library for React:

https://react-table.js.org/

My only issue is that I need to "freeze" the first (left most) column so that it's always in "view" when a user is scrolling sideways to view the other columns. I've poured over the documentation and didn't find any references, so I don't think there is a way to do this without hacking up the source code.

Comment: https://github.com/react-tools/react-table/issues/848

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixed column in ReactTable component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48080117/fixed-column-in-reacttable-component)

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been temporarily resolved with an external library:

https://guillaumejasmin.github.io/react-table-hoc-fixed-columns/

Example:

```
import createTable from 'react-table-hoc-fixed-columns';

const ReactTableFixedColumns = createTable(ReactTable);

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
...
...
...
render(){

<ReactTableFixedColumns
  data={this.state.data}

  // Fixed Column(s)
  columns = {[
               {
                  Header: "Name",
                  id: "name_id",
                  fixed: true,
                  accessor: d => d.name,
               },
   // Scrollable Column(s)            
  {columns: [
               {
                  Header: "Address",
                  id: "address_id",
                  accessor: d => d.address,
               },
               .
               .
               .        
            ]}
          ]}
```