# React table v7 fixed column with react-window

Tags: css, reactjs, react-table, react-window

I have a table with react-table v7. Have used react-window for virtualisation. Now the table has last column fixed but I am unable to fix the last column of the table. React-window's internal element has `overflow: auto` which is not letting the column to be sticky at last.

Here's the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-tharp-s1ksy?file=/src/App.js) reproduce the issue.

I am trying to achieve something around [these](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-cori-gl81g) lines.

If you see the issue link, I want the last row to be fixed at a position and keep the rest horizontally scrollable.

Comment: can you add some code as well? thanks

Comment: have updated the question @tudor.gergely

Comment: @priyanshusinha are you trying to say the firstname and lastname and last column needs to be sticky ?

Comment: @XxSTREKxX I want the entire `Row Index` column to be sticky.

Comment: @priyanshusinha Have you tried https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-virtual? It's from the author of react-table itself and very easy to setup. Here is an example: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-virtual#sample

Comment: since react-window is being used all through the application I would like to stick to react-window if it's possible @HardikModha

Comment: also, I don't think using react-virtual will solve the problem. @HardikModha

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the exact the issue?

Answer (score 2):

For sticky header you should implement *innerElementType* props as react-window said like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/0mk3qwpl4l).

But for sticky column maybe more standard way of that is to use another grid or list beside that and sync their scroll position like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/2jvl09przn) one.

you could also use [react-base-table](https://github.com/Autodesk/react-base-table) which implement whole side sticky rows and columns.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this exact same issue.  I came up with a solution that:

1. Add a className to the <FixedSizeList className={styles.fixedList} ...>
2. Add css to override the scroll:  .fixedList { overflow: unset !important; }

Once I did this, it allowed my sticky column to be 'sticky' again.  I hope this helps you as well.

Comment: Doesnt work, as you then cant scroll, due to the dependence of overflow:hidden - Or at least, that's what im experiencing... Do you have an example of this where it works with sticky columns and scroll still working?

Answer (score 0):

Sticky columns and rows could be implemented by using `innerElementType` property of `FixedSizeList` provided by `react-window`.

Here's a working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-field-48x39?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

Hi I created this reusable react component

- it uses only react-window with custom sticky columns implementation
- i have lot of columns so i need column virtualization too

> https://codesandbox.io/s/react-window-sticky-grid-forked-kkcf2z?file=/src/CustomVirtualGrid.js

[image]